# Cannot read property 'channesl' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

```
bot.guilds.get(636288911538389032).channels.get(724665013356199986).send(embed).
   catch(console.log(`Message recieved from ${userID}!(${message.author.username})`))
```

what is the problem?

Comment: If you are using discord.js v12 you will need `bot.guilds.cache.get('ID').channels.cache.get('ID')`
As said here: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#managers-cache
Also why are you using a catch after the `send(embed)` ? It will only run if the bot is not able to send the embed, if you want it to console.log something after the message is received you will need to use `.then()`

Comment: Please spend more time when you're asking a question. This looks like an ultra-low-effort question that disregards all the information and tips that StackOverflow provides to new users. No context, no formatting, error message and code don't match... You will hardly get a good answer for such a question.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let findGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD_ID') //Using .get() to find the guild by ID
    let findChannel = client.channels.cache.get('CHANNEL_ID') //Using .get() to find the channel by ID

    if(findGuild) { //If guildID exists it will send embed to findChannel
    findChannel.send(embed)
  }
```